# Generating MD5 for a json with powershell

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to generate a JSON object for each file (with path) in a folder with it's MD5?

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Games.dll",
        "md5": "4cd9e9a5efad4cceb01b3e41a047e489"
    }, {
        "Name": "Files/Image/Bg.png",
        "md5": "4cd9e9a5efad4cceb01b3e41a047e489"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should do what you need

`Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 | Select-Object @{name="Name";expression={$_.Path}}, @{name="md5";expression={$_.Hash}} | ConvertTo-Json`

Answer (score 4):

How to create a json file that contains file name, path, and md5 hash of all files in a folder using PowerShell 5.1

Takes a little more than one second per file.

```
pushd $env:userprofile\desktop
Get-FileHash (gci *.*) -Algorithm MD5 | convertto-json | out-file hash.json
popd 
exit
```

[powershell hash md5](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20gci%20all%20files)

[powershell generate a JSON object for each file](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20generate%20a%20JSON%20object%20for%20each%20file)